# How to reference a junction table on ERD?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, entity-relationship, erd

Here in my ERD I wanted to solve the m-n relationship, so i have created a junction tables.
but i feel something is missing with using the keys.

Please guide me [below is my ERD schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7HhJ.jpg)

Comment: i feel something is missing.

Comment: Your ERD has about 20 tables in it. How are you expecting anyone to know which one is the junction table you are referring to? Also “i feel something is missing” is a very vague statement: what do you think is missing and why?

Comment: the junction table i meant was "customerstore", how do i connect it to the main  table "salesorder" ? it has a composite key (customerid, storeid) .. again, what forighn key should i put in the main table?

Comment: Pleaese clarify via edits, not comments. Where are you 1st stuck following what published presentation of what design method? Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. [ask] [Help]

Comment: See [How do comment replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/266284) to learn to use `@x` to notify one non-sole non-poster commenter `x` re a comment. Posters, sole commenters & followers of posts always get notified.

Answer (score 1):

On the Customer table you need to drop the StoreID column. Apart from that it looks ok